# Switching between 2 env files in a single deployment in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

We have an application that users can switch between Sandbox and Live environment.

Depending on the environment they are in, the application is supposed to use different env file credentials.

At the moment, we deployed the Sandbox and the Live application separately but managing them is stressful.

Do you have any suggestions on how we can deploy a single application and switch environment files easily?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/envoy)?

```
@servers(['web' => '127.0.0.1'])

@setup

    $env = isset($env) ? $env : "production";

@endsetup
```

You can pass it as a variable to the envoy command.

```
envoy run deploy --env=development
```